# Has any Hindu queen directly ruled without her husband?

Tags: dharma, governance, feminism

Modern day feminist media in movies and TV shows, like the movie "Bahubali", portrays "strong and independent" female characters ruling countries as queens without their husband (the king) being alive or present. This is done by the writers to promote feminism and to show that women ruling is normal and that they can rule independently.

Has any Hindu queen directly ruled without her husband according to scriptures?

Comment: The name of the movie is "Bahubali".  Hence, the content of the question was corrected.  By the way,  in the movie, the queen's husband was very much alive but disabled person.  As his younger brother, who was ruling, was dead, she takes over, duly crushing the coup attempt. Thus, it was portrayed partly from Mahabharata.:-)

Comment: I believe so. In Mahabharat, when Arjuna goes on Tirtha yatra, he marries a woman 'Chitrangada', whose father lays down the condition, that she, and their son would stay back in that kingdom instead of following Arjuna, because their lineage always had only 1 heir, and since it was not guaranteed to be a son, whoever it was, would rule that region.

Comment: Pooradam Thirunal Sethu Lakshmi Bayi was the sole ruler of Travancore, a Hindu state, between 1924 and 1931. She was the only female to ever carry the title of the servant of Sri Padmanabha (she was called Sri Padmanabhasevini). This is not a scriptural source, but I think it is important to be mentioned anyway as Travancorean royals orthodoxly followed Vedic culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Chudala** is one such queen who ruled without her husband.

The husband of Chudala, Sikhidvaja, left home and kingdom suddenly without intimating anyone including his wife.

Chudala understands the state of mind of her husband and plans to bring him back. The execution of the plan takes some time. In between, Chudala rules the kingdom without telling the people of the kingdom the actual reason.

> After the prince had
> gone away from the palace at midnight, Chudala started from her sleep;
> as a timid fawn lying in the village, is startled by fear. She found
> the bed vacated by her husband and thought it as dreary as the sky,
> without the sun and moon. (A deserted wife is as forlorn as a deserted
> village or desolate country). She rose up with a melancholy face, and
> with her heart full of sorrow and sadness; and her limbs were as lank
> as the leaves of plants, without being well watered in summer. Sorrow
> sat heavy in her heart, and drove the charm and cheerfulness off her
> countenance; and she remained as a winter day, over cast by a cloud or
> covered by a hoar-frost over its face. She sat awhile on the bedstead,
> and thought with sorrow in herself; saying, "Ah woe unto me" that my
> lord is gone away from here, and abandoned a kingdom for a retreat in
> the woods. What then can I do now, than repair to my husband; where he
> is, because it is appointed both by the law of nature and God, that
> the husband is the only resort and support of the wife. Having thought
> so, Chudala rose up to follow her husband and she fled by the door of
> a window into the open air. (This means that her spirit fled into air,
> by the power of her yoga). She roamed in her aerial course, and by the
> force of her breath on the wings of air; and appeared before the face
> of the aerial spirits (siddhas), as a second moon moving in the skies.
> As she was passing at the night time, she happened to behold her lord
> roving about with a sword in his hand; and appearing as a ghost of a
> vetala or demon wandering in the solitary forest. The princess seeing
> her husband in this manner from her aerial seat, she began to reflect
> on the future state which awaited on her husband; and which she
> foresaw by power of her yoga. It is certain, O Rama! that whatever is
> allotted in the book of fate to befall on any body at any time or
> place or manner, the same is sure to take place at the very moment and
> spot and in the same way (and all this is well known to the holy seer
> and seeress by the prophetic power, which they acquire by their
> knowledge and practice of yoga). The princess seeing plainly in her
> presence, whatever is to take place on her husband; and knowing it to
> be averted by no means, she stopped from going to him to communicate
> the same. Be my visit postponed to him to a future occasion, when it
> is destined for me to be in his company again. Thinking so in her mind
> Chudala turned her course from him, and returned to her inner
> apartment and reclined on her milk white pillow; as the crescent of
> the moon lies recumbent on the hoary forehead of Hara. **She proclaimed
> to her people, that the prince was gone on some important occasion;
> and having relieved with the consolation of his quick return, she took
> the reins of the government in her own hands. She managed the state in
> the manner of her husband, according to the established rules of
> toleration; and with the same care and vigilance, as the husband-woman
> guards her ripening cornfields.** In this manner they passed their days
> without seeing one another, and the conjugal pair lived separated from
> each other; in their respective habitations of the royal palace and
> the solitary forest.
>
> [[1-18, Section 85: Investigation into true happiness, 6: nirvana prakarana, Yoga Vasistha]](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118629.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One such regent queen was Chitrangada, wife of Arjuna. When Arjuna asked her father, King Chitravahana, for her hand in marriage this is what the latter [said](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01218.htm)

> There was in our race a king of the name of Prabhanjana, who was childless. To obtain a child, he underwent severe ascetic penances. By his severe asceticism, O Partha, he gratified that god of gods, Mahadeva, the husband of Uma, that supreme Lord holding (the mighty bow called) Pinaka. The illustrious Lord granted him the boon that each successive descendant of his race should have one child only. In consequence of that boon only one child is born unto every successive descendant of this race. All my ancestors (one after another) had each a male child. **I, however, have only a daughter to perpetuate my race. But, O bull amongst men, I ever look upon this daughter of mine as my son. O bull of Bharata's race, I have duly made her a Putrika**. Therefore, one amongst the sons that may be begotten upon her by thee, O Bharata, shall be the perpetuator of my race. That son is the dower for which I may give away my daughter. O son of Pandu, if them choosest, thou canst take her upon this understanding.'

As we know Arjuna didn't stick around to rule Manipur. He left after three years when his son Vabhruvahana was born.

However from this answer it can't be concluded that Queen regents was the norm. The exception here was because Chitravahana could not have another child. He would not have been able to procreate another child even if he married several times.

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted because this answer is not saying what you think it's saying. A "putrika" is simply a daughter through whom the father continues his male lineage. Her becoming a putrika doesn't imply that she ruled as a queen. A "putrika" is specifically defined in many dharma shastras to specifically mean, "a daughter through whom
 one continues his male lineage."

Comment: Putrika is handing over to daughter's son, not  daughter herself. There isnt any reference of Chithra gadga becoming the ruler.

Comment: @Ikshvaku - i am unsure why definition of putrika matters. Point is tnat Chritra gadga was ruling as regent queen..Chitravahana didn't allow her daughter to be taken away by Arjuna as was the norm

Comment: "Chritra gadga was ruling as regent queen" - But the verse you quoted doesn't say that, or am I missing it?